# Apex convert &#39 and &quot to apostrophe and quotes

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura, html

Does anyone know how to fix this one.

In Aura component (Apex - Salesforce) in **.cmp,** I have these lines of code:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!chat.Number == message.Number}">
     {!message.value}
</aura:if>
```

The problem is once when it try to show `message.value`, it convert ' (apostrophe), " (quotes)..into &#39, &quot...

So, for example, instead of showing `He hasn't..` it shows `He hasn&#39t..`

I want to show '(apostrophe) instead of &#39 and etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your `{!message.value}` inside [Lightning formatted richtext](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedRichText/example) to resolve the problem. e.g.

`<lightning:formattedRichText value="{!message.value}"/>`

Comment: Thanks, it works.